# Как при hover сделать чтобы второе меню не пропадало?

Tags: javascript, css3, html5

```css
.menu-list {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  background-color: #888;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
      -ms-flex-pack: justify;
          justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-family: "HelveticaNeueCyr-Medium";
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-top: 15px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3; }
  .menu-list a {
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none; }
    .menu-list a > i {
      margin-left: 5px;
      margin-top: 5px;
      font-size: 15px; }
    .menu-list a:hover {
      color: #e23939; }

.menu_list2 {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  display: none; }

.us:hover .menu_list2 {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  height: 100px;
  top: 48px; }

.menu__item2 {
  background-color: #000;
  padding: 5px 20px; }

.menu__item2 > a {
  color: #fff; }
```

```html
<ul class="menu-list">
  <li class="menu-list__item"><a href="#">Главная</a></li>
  <li class="menu-list__item"><a href="#">Ремонт стартеров</a></li>
  <li class="menu-list__item"><a href="#">Ремонт генераторов </a></li>
  <li class="menu-list__item us"><a href="#">Все услуги<i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></a>
  <ul class="menu_list2">
    <li class="menu__item2"><a href="#">все услуги</a></li>
    <li class="menu__item2"><a href="#">все услуги</a></li>
    <li class="menu__item2"><a href="#">все услуги</a></li>
    <li class="menu__item2"><a href="#">все услуги</a></li>
    <li class="menu__item2"><a href="#">все услуги</a></li>
  </ul>       
  </li>
  <li class="menu-list__item"><a href="#">Цены</a></li>
  <li class="menu-list__item"><a href="#">Каталог</a></li>
  <li class="menu-list__item us"><a href="#">Доставка<i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></a>
    <ul class="menu_list2">
    <li class="menu__item2"><a href="#">все услуги</a></li>
    <li class="menu__item2"><a href="#">все услуги</a></li>
    <li class="menu__item2"><a href="#">все услуги</a></li>
    <li class="menu__item2"><a href="#">все услуги</a></li>
    <li class="menu__item2"><a href="#">все услуги</a></li>
  </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-list__item"><a href="#">оплата</a></li>
  <li class="menu-list__item"><a href="#">О нас</a></li>
  <li class="menu-list__item"><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Заменил я вот тут вместо top:48px поставил padding-top

```
.us:hover .menu_list2 {      
padding-top: 48px;
```

}

```css
.menu-list {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  background-color: #888;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
      -ms-flex-pack: justify;
          justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-family: "HelveticaNeueCyr-Medium";
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-top: 15px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3; }
  .menu-list a {
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none; }
    .menu-list a > i {
      margin-left: 5px;
      margin-top: 5px;
      font-size: 15px; }
    .menu-list a:hover {
      color: #e23939; }

.menu_list2 {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  display: none; }

.us:hover .menu_list2 {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  height: 100px;
padding-top: 48px;}
.menu__item2 {
  background-color: #000;
  padding: 5px 20px; }

.menu__item2 > a {
  color: #fff; }
```

```html
<ul class="menu-list">
  <li class="menu-list__item"><a href="#">Главная</a></li>
  <li class="menu-list__item"><a href="#">Ремонт стартеров</a></li>
  <li class="menu-list__item"><a href="#">Ремонт генераторов </a></li>
  <li class="menu-list__item us"><a href="#">Все услуги<i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></a>
  <ul class="menu_list2">
    <li class="menu__item2"><a href="#">все услуги</a></li>
    <li class="menu__item2"><a href="#">все услуги</a></li>
    <li class="menu__item2"><a href="#">все услуги</a></li>
    <li class="menu__item2"><a href="#">все услуги</a></li>
    <li class="menu__item2"><a href="#">все услуги</a></li>
  </ul>       
  </li>
  <li class="menu-list__item"><a href="#">Цены</a></li>
  <li class="menu-list__item"><a href="#">Каталог</a></li>
  <li class="menu-list__item us"><a href="#">Доставка<i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></a>
    <ul class="menu_list2">
    <li class="menu__item2"><a href="#">все услуги</a></li>
    <li class="menu__item2"><a href="#">все услуги</a></li>
    <li class="menu__item2"><a href="#">все услуги</a></li>
    <li class="menu__item2"><a href="#">все услуги</a></li>
    <li class="menu__item2"><a href="#">все услуги</a></li>
  </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-list__item"><a href="#">оплата</a></li>
  <li class="menu-list__item"><a href="#">О нас</a></li>
  <li class="menu-list__item"><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
</ul>
```